# How to finish array question, it always repeating

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Hi everyone I need help.
I have this code
I have 50 question string and I want if already 10 question appears then the game finish. thank you for your help

```
private Question mQuestion = new Question();

private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionLenght = 5 ;

Random r;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    r = new Random();


    answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    answer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);

    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    score.setText("Score: " + mScore  );

    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionLenght));


    answer4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(answer4.getText() == mAnswer){
                mScore++;
                score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionLenght));
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void updateQuestion(int num){
    question.setText(mQuestion.getQuestion(num));
    answer1.setText(mQuestion.getChoice1(num));
    answer2.setText(mQuestion.getChoice2(num));
    answer3.setText(mQuestion.getChoice3(num));
    answer4.setText(mQuestion.getChoice4(num));
    mAnswer = mQuestion.getCorrectAnswer(num);

}
private void gameOver(){
```

}

i have 50 question i want if user already answer 10 question game stop and show score. in that code it cant stop if they wrong answer game can stop but if user always right game load all question

Comment: `answer4.getText() == mAnswer` is this condition ever becomes false ?

Comment: Create a counter, and when it reach ten, go to gameOver() instead of next question

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, please update question with more code and with a detailed description

Comment: i cant place my whole code here.

Comment: can you please explain some more about your requirement. Now we can't understand what you need actually

Comment: Sorry my bad. 
i have 50 question i want if user already answer 10 question game stop and show score. in that code it cant stop if they wrong answer game can stop but if user always  right game load all question

Answer (score 1):

In your Acitivty, add a counter attribute

```
private int numberOfQuestionsAsked = 0;
```

After each question asked, add 1 to your counter

```
if(answer4.getText().equals(mAnswer)){ //note : use .equals() and not == !
    mScore++;
    numberOfQuestionsAsked++;
    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionLenght));
}
```

After the user answered a question, check if the counterhas reached 10, if yes, go to gameOver

```
if(numberOfQuestionsAsked <= 10) {
    gameOver();
}
```

In gameOver, reset the counter so the game can restart

```
numberOfQuestionsAsked = 0;
```

Your code should look like

```
private Question mQuestion = new Question();

private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionLenght = 5 ;
private int numberOfQuestionsAsked = 0;

Random r;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    r = new Random();


    answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    answer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);

    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    score.setText("Score: " + mScore  );

    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionLenght));


    answer4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(answer4.getText().equals(mAnswer)){ //note : use .equals() and not == !
                mScore++;
                score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionLenght));
                numberOfQuestionsAsked++;
            } else {
                gameOver();
            }
            if(numberOfQuestionsAsked <= 10) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void updateQuestion(int num){
    question.setText(mQuestion.getQuestion(num));
    answer1.setText(mQuestion.getChoice1(num));
    answer2.setText(mQuestion.getChoice2(num));
    answer3.setText(mQuestion.getChoice3(num));
    answer4.setText(mQuestion.getChoice4(num));
    mAnswer = mQuestion.getCorrectAnswer(num);

}
private void gameOver(){
        numberOfQuestionsAsked = 0;
}
```

Comment: hi thankyou for your but it still morthen 10 question. can i ask you in email or something im already stuck for 3 days

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter in your code like this :

Int counter = 0;

```
if(counter <= 10 ){
    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionLenght));
    counter++;
} else {
    gameOver();
}
```

Add this and check, hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.onClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view instanceOf (TextView) && ((TextView)view).getText().toString().equals(mAnswer)){
            mScore++;
            score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
            if(mScore >= 10) {
                gameCompleted();//ToDo
            } else {
                updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionLenght));
            }
        } else {
            gameOver();
        }
    }
};
```

Then, use this listener in every answer.
Futhermore, your random number may fail because it can be higher than 50 and can be a repeated answer and your text comparison is not recommended, you could use an object which assigns an id to the text.

Enjoy coding.

Comment: Please, check my answer as correct if it works. Thanks!